# I wanted to CREATE a Database Table, which datatype is better for storing alphanumeric values?

Tags: database

The variable must be able to contain a maximum of 12 alphanumeric characters and uniquely identify the row. For this which datatype do you advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For alphanumeric values obviously you will have to use varchar and to specify length use it like below

YourField      varchar(12)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the problem if we use the Varchar2() or Char()?